# Get access_token working calling API on same IS4 webapp

Tags: authorization, identityserver4, identity

I'm trying to get the this access_token stuff working to do a call to a API which is declared with an Autohorize attrib from a BaseController. I think there is something wrong with my configuration.
Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I have attached my Startup.cs for reference.
I'm trying to get a access token to send with the API called in the code below:

```
   var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(BaseController.AUTHORIZATION_SERVICE_CLIENT_NAME);
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.Accept, "application/json");

//AccessToken is always null
   var accessToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result;
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

   var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/api/auth/user/?id=" + id);
   var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result as string;
   return "-";
```

My IS4 startup:
Confi

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddMvc().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

    services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
        });

//START IS4
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
    options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
    options.Authentication = new AuthenticationOptions()
    {
        CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromHours(10), // ID server cookie timeout set to 10 hours
        CookieSlidingExpiration = true
    };
})
.AddConfigurationStore(options =>
{
    options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
})
.AddOperationalStore(options =>
{
    options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
})
.AddAspNetIdentity<User>();

if (env.IsDevelopment())
    builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
else
    builder.AddSigningCredential(LoadCertificateFromStore());

//END IS4

//START IDENTITY
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
.AddUserStore<CustomUserStore>()
.AddRoleStore<CustomRoleStore>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders()
.AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.LoginPath = Startup.LoginPath;
    options.LogoutPath = Startup.LogoutPath;
    options.AccessDeniedPath = Startup.AccessDeniedPath;
});

services.AddAuthentication(o =>{})
      .AddGoogle("Google", "Google", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
            options.ClientId = configuration.GetValue<string>("Google:ClientId");
            options.ClientSecret = configuration.GetValue<string>("Google:ClientSecret");
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("azuread", "Azure AD", options => configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>("azuread", options =>
{
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = context =>
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            context.Response.Redirect("/Identity/Account/Logout");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    };
});

services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();

//END IDENTITY

    //Set named HttpClient settings for API to get roles of user
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();            
    services.AddTransient<BearerTokenHandler>();
    services.AddHttpClient(BaseController.AUTHORIZATION_SERVICE_CLIENT_NAME, client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44318/");
    }).AddHttpMessageHandler<BearerTokenHandler>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(ErrorPath);
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseIdentityServer();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "defaultArea",
            pattern: "{area=Identity}/{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

Bearer token handler, when I add 'AddHttpMessageHandler<BearerTokenHandler' to the client it gives null at the 'expiresAt' variable;

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var accessToken = await GetAccessTokenAsync();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accessToken))
        request.SetBearerToken(accessToken);

    return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}

public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
{
    // get the expires_at value & parse it
    var expiresAt = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("expires_at");
    var expiresAtAsDateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(expiresAt, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    if ((expiresAtAsDateTimeOffset.AddSeconds(-60)).ToUniversalTime() > DateTime.UtcNow)
        return await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken); // no need to refresh, return the access token

    var idpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("IDPClient");

    // get the discovery document
    var discoveryReponse = await idpClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync();

    // refresh the tokens
    var refreshToken = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken);

    var refreshResponse = await idpClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(new RefreshTokenRequest {
            Address = discoveryReponse.TokenEndpoint,
            ClientId = "mvc",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            RefreshToken = refreshToken
        });

    // store the tokens             
    var updatedTokens = new List<AuthenticationToken>();
    updatedTokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken {
        Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken,
        Value = refreshResponse.IdentityToken
    });
    updatedTokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken {
        Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken,
        Value = refreshResponse.AccessToken
    });
    updatedTokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken {
        Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken,
        Value = refreshResponse.RefreshToken
    });
    updatedTokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken {
        Name = "expires_at",
        Value = (DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(refreshResponse.ExpiresIn)).
                ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    });

    // get authenticate result, containing the current principal & properties
    var currentAuthenticateResult = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    // store the updated tokens
    currentAuthenticateResult.Properties.StoreTokens(updatedTokens);

    // sign in
    await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, currentAuthenticateResult.Principal, currentAuthenticateResult.Properties);

    return refreshResponse.AccessToken;
}
```

Comment: It gets quite messy when you put IdentityServer and all the other authentication features in the same appliation. Its must better to put IdentityServer on its own service, to get a better separation of concern and it will be easier to understand.

Comment: I have separated it in areas and IHostingStartups, one for IS4 stuff and one for Identity etc. I followed the step-by-step instructions at [link](https://deblokt.com/2019/09/23/04-part-1-identityserver4-asp-net-core-identity/).
But do you also have an idear were it goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One idea could be to try to set the SaveTokens=true in your configuration.

See this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-3.1#save-the-access-token) or ideas.

Comment: I have set savetokens to true in the .AddGoogle("Google"... and .AddOpenIdConnect("azuread"... But no success, where should I put it in the code above?
Maybe important to know that I login with username and password, instead via Google or AzureAd. It looks like the User tokens/claims aren't send with the requests.